# Unix/Linux: Convert fixed-width file to csv and subset on two columns

Tags: unix, subset

I have [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/Parse.txt) fixed-width file with the widths being 34, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2 and 75 which I want to (a) convert to delimited (csv) format  and then (b) subset according to V2="03" and V5="1". I have figured out the first step:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='34 2 3 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 2 75' -v OFS=',' '{ $1=$1 ""; print }' </filepath/Parse.txt > /filepath/Parse.csv
```

But I am stumped at step 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='...' -v OFS=',' '($2=="03") && ($5=="1"){ $1=$1 ""; print }'
```

Comment: Hi Mat... I think this is simply overwriting the values of V3 and V5 with 03 and 1 instead of subsetting the original file.

Comment: Sorry, bad typo. Should obviously be `==` in the comparisons.