# Piping unix commands

Tags: r, unix

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102694/unix-linux-convert-fixed-width-file-to-csv-and-subset-on-two-columns) question. I have [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/pipe.txt) fixed-width file, where the columns-widths are 34 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2  and 65. I want to read this into R after dropping the first and last columns, where the second column has the value "07". Thanks to Mat, if I just want to convert the txt file to csv, I can do it with this code:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='34 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 65' -v OFS=',' '($2=='07'){ $1=$1 ''; print }' </filepath/pipe.txt | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=2- > /filepath/parsed.csv
```

Of course, I can then read the `parsed.csv` file in. But I am trying to do it one shot with `pipe()`. when I try to pipe this in R, it hangs:

```
a = read.csv(pipe("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='34 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 65' -v OFS=',' '($2=='07'){ $1=$1 ''; print }' 
                  </filepath/pipe.txt 
                  | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=2-")
             , header=F, colClasses="character")
```

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED to your title, but tick the correct answer... In addition, you might want to change your name from the default generated one to a more meaningfull one (but this is just my opinion).

Comment: Paul, I added "solved" because there was no "correct" answer. The problem was in the question itself, which realization I stumbled upon by myself. Please see shelter's note below.

Comment: I understand the situation. I would recommend you edit your answer to include a description of what solved your problem, and accept this answer. This is perfectly acceptable on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about `pipe()` but I would do it with `system()`.

```
library(stringr)
txt <- system("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='34 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 65' -v OFS=',' '($2=='07'){ $1=$1 ''; print }' < pipe.txt | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=2-", intern=T)
do.call(rbind, str_split(txt, ","))
```

Answer (score 0):

jigr (and other readers)-  I found the strangest quirk in R/RStudio. The code in my question works perfectly, provided there is no line-break:

```
a = read.csv(pipe("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='34 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 65' -v OFS=',''($2=='07'){ $1=$1 ''; print }' </filepath/pipe.txt | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=2-"), header=F, colClasses="character")
```

I don't have the slightest idea why this is happening.

Comment: This is the way the shell works. You could also have moved just the '|' char up and it would have worked because then the shell 'parser' expects that the command is continued on the next line. Speaking of continuing, you could also use '\' (without the single-quotes) at the end of the first line. It is often known as the continuation char and must be the last char on the line, spaces after it will mess things up. Good luck.